# Windows 10 UDP Socket Benchmark a lot faster in safe mode

Tags: windows-10, networking, performance, safe-mode, benchmarking

[image: UDP Socket Performance]

I made a simple SendReceive benchmark for UDP sockets and noticed, that the perofrmance in Windows safe mode is considerably faster than in normal mode. Why is this the case? In normal mode I was very careful to kill any non necessary processes and also didn't see any other process eating up CPU time while the benchmark was running (like the Defender). You can reproduce the problem with the repo on github: https://github.com/JohannesDeml/MicroBenchmarksDotNet.

I noticed this problem originally for full fledged low level networking libraries I was benchmarking ([NetworkBenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/JohannesDeml/NetworkBenchmarkDotNet)).

Here are the results of the benchmark:

| Method | Library | Safe Mode (ms) | Normal Mode (ms) | Slowdown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PingPongUnreliable | ENet | 2,798.70 | 5,003.60 | 78.78% |
| PingPongBatchedUnreliable | ENet | 488.4 | 668.2 | 36.81% |
| PingPongUnreliable | NetCoreServer | 4,101.40 | 6,642.10 | 61.95% |
| PingPongBatchedUnreliable | NetCoreServer | 3,580.80 | 6,037.30 | 68.60% |
| PingPongUnreliable | LiteNetLib | 2,873.40 | 5,161.40 | 79.63% |
| PingPongBatchedUnreliable | LiteNetLib | 535.7 | 573 | 6.96% |

All details can be found in this [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PDuVeBs8FS05M0QWpleBKsmHq4K2op5Tc-BbHHI_Wik/edit#gid=660933421).

For normal mode and safe mode I used the command line in admin mode and tried to have no other processes running (see spreadsheet above for a detailed list of all processes running in both instances). I also added the benchmark folder and the dotnet sdk folder to the Windows Defender Antivirus Exclusion list. I also couldn't see any other process spining up the CPU when I run the benchmark in normal mode.

Why is there such a difference between normal and safe mode? When I researched on the web, I couldn't find any explanation or note that sockets are throttled or something similar? Any idea what I can try in normal mode to get the same performance statistics?